# Why using union, result of 2 queries is mixing in SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I want to append result of 2 queries. For example:

ResultOfQuery_1

ResultOfQuery_2

My query is :

```
SELECT Id FName,SortString  
     FROM CTable 
     WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString glob '[A-Z]*'      
UNION 
SELECT FName,SortString 
     FROM CTable 
     WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString NOT glob '[A-Z]*' ORDER BY FName DESC
```

As an output of this query both results are mixing. I want them one after other.

Can anyone help me get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case Order by is applying to whole query. If we could use brackets it wold be like

```
(
SELECT Id FName,SortString  
     FROM CTable 
     WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString glob '[A-Z]*'      
UNION 
SELECT FName,SortString 
     FROM CTable 
     WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString NOT glob '[A-Z]*' 
)
ORDER BY FName DESC
```

You might use some ordering field

```
SELECT Id, FName,SortString, 1 as OrderStr
    FROM CTable 
    WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString glob '[A-Z]*'      
UNION 
SELECT Id, FName,SortString, 2 as OrderStr
    FROM CTable 
    WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString NOT glob '[A-Z]*' 
ORDER BY OrderStr, FName DESC
```

Or maybe sub-queries

```
SELECT *
    FROM(
        SELECT Id, FName,SortString
        FROM CTable 
        WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString glob '[A-Z]*'  
        ORDER BY FName DESC
        ) T1
UNION 
SELECT *
    FROM(
        SELECT Id, FName,SortString
        FROM CTable 
        WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString NOT glob '[A-Z]*'  
        ORDER BY FName DESC
        ) T2
```

Comment: UNION always sorts (to efficiently remove duplicates); you need to use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Then do a `JOIN` on `sortstring` column instead of `UNION`  like

```
select xx.Id, xx.FName as xxFName,
xx.SortString as xxSortString,
xxx.fname, xxx.SortString
from (
SELECT Id FName,SortString  
     FROM CTable 
     WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString glob '[A-Z]*'  ) xx
join (
SELECT FName,SortString 
     FROM CTable 
     WHERE '1' = DevId AND SortString NOT glob '[A-Z]*' ) xxx
on xx.sortstring = xxx.sortstring
 ORDER BY xx.FName DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single query:

```
SELECT Id FName,SortString  
FROM CTable 
WHERE 1 = DevId 
ORDER BY (SortString glob '[A-Z]*') DESC, FNAME DESC ;
```

If `DevId` is a number, then do not use single quotes around the comparison.  I removed the single quotes, assuming that it is a number.

Comment: Thanks :) but I wanted 2 separate query's result to be appended.

Comment: @srb_programming . . . This is the simplest answer to accomplish what you are asking.